# Virasoro operators commutation relations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, operators, conformal-field-theory, commutator

For the commutation relation in quantising the bosonic string

$$\left[L_n,L_{m}\right]=(n-m)L_{n+m}+\frac{D}{12}n(n^2-1)\delta_{n+m,0}$$

we can then calculate this for $m=-n$ in between the vacuum state i.e.

$$\boxed{\left<0,0|\left[L_n,L_{-n}\right]|0,0\right>=\frac{D}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m(n-m)\left<0,0|0,0\right>=\frac{D}{12}n(n^2-1)\left<0,0|0,0\right>} \, .$$

The second expression I can't seem to show explicitly although I know we can can write

$$\left<0,0|\left[L_n,L_{-n}\right]|0,0\right>=\left<0,0|L_n,L_{-n}|0,0\right>=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sum_{p=1}^{n-1}\left<0,0|\alpha_m\alpha_{n-m}\alpha_{n-p}^{\dagger}\alpha_p^{\dagger}|0,0\right>$$

and then it's surely something to do with how these $\alpha$'s act on the vacuum state. However, why the $m(n-m)$ and where's the $\frac{D}{2}$ come from?

Finally, the last term in the boxed calculation is obviously found from the commutation relation of $\left[L_n,L_{m}\right]$, but therefore $\left<0,0|L_0|0,0\right>=0$. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

**To show:**
 $$\boxed{\left<0,0|\left[L_n,L_{-n}\right]|0,0\right>=<0,0|n^2L_0+\frac{D}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m(n-m)\left|0,0\right>=<0,0|\frac{D}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m(n-m)\left|0,0\right>= \frac{D}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m(n-m)\left<0,0|0,0\right> = \frac{D}{12}n(n^2-1).}$$

**Why is the first term vanishing?**

To see that $\left<0,0|n^2L_0|0,0\right> =0$ one can use the algebra commutator relation and write $$ 2 L_0 |0,0 \rangle = (L_1 L_{-1} - L_{-1} L_1) |0,0\rangle =0 $$ as done in Polchinski, p 59. The expression is zero, because the $L_{\pm 1}$ can be viewed as [normal ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order) $$L_n=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} : \alpha_{n} \alpha_{-n} :$$ with all annihilation operators to the right destroying the $|0,0 \rangle$.

**Why is $\frac{D}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m(n-m)=\frac{D}{12}n(n^2-1)$ ?**

Let's decompose the sum in 2 terms  $$\frac{D}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m(n-m) = \frac{D}{2} n \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m -\frac{D}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m^2 $$
The first sum can be identified with one known [finite series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Sums_of_powers) $\sum_{k=1}^l k =\frac{l(l+1)}{2}$ giving 
$$\frac{D}{2} n \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m = \frac{D}{2}n\frac{(n-1)n}{2}.$$
The second sum can be identified with another finite series [from the same list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Sums_of_powers) $ \sum_{k=1}^l k^2 = \frac{l(l+1)(2l+1)}{6}$  giving $$\frac{D}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m^2= \frac{D}{2} \frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}.$$
Subtracting the second sum from the first one arrives at desired result $$\boxed{\frac{D}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m(n-m)=\frac{D}{12}n(n^2-1)}.$$